# Execute JQuery function when the page is loaded instead on .keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload

I have a function that look like that

```
var text_max = 200;
$('#count_message').html('0 / ' + text_max );

$('#text').keyup(function() {
  var text_length = $('#text').val().length;
  var text_remaining = text_max - text_length;

  $('#count_message').html(text_length + ' / ' + text_max);
});
```

And what I am trying to achieve is it to be executed immediately after the page is loaded, meaning that it counts the text length for the already existing text in the textarea and not after you type something.

I have tried putting it in a function like that

```
function myFunction() {

var text_max = 200;
$('#count_message').html('0 / ' + text_max );

$('#text').keyup(function() {
  var text_length = $('#text').val().length;
  var text_remaining = text_max - text_length;

  $('#count_message').html(text_length + ' / ' + text_max);
});

}
```

And then executing it in the body like that

```
<body onload="myFunction()">
```

But I am not doing something right or maybe that's not the way to do it.
I have my suspicions that I have to do something within the .keyup(function() and not just loading it in the body but not really sure what to do. I have tried to find something in the jQuery Event Methods that I can use but couldn't find anything that works. Also, tried some ideas I found here but it did not work either.

Here is where I got the original script from https://www.codeply.com/go/s0F9Iz38yn/bootstrap-textarea-with-character-count-_-bootstrap-3

**EDIT**
I want to keep the .keyup functionality but also to count when the page is loaded

Comment: Remove the `keyup` listener from `myFunction()`, move all the code under the `keyup` handler directly under `myFunction()`

Comment: remove keyup and insert call inside $(document).ready(); https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: Yeah, that would work i guess, but then it will not be triggered again when the user type something. Maybe I was not clear in my explanation. I will edit the initial question.

Comment: Then also attach `myFunction()` as a `keyup` handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the keyup outside from the function and call it on load like,

```
var text_max = 200;
function myFunction($txt) {
   var text_length = $txt.val().length;
   var text_remaining = text_max - text_length;
   $('#count_message').html(text_length + ' / ' + text_max);    
}
$(function(){
   $('#text').keyup(function(){
       myFunction($(this));
   });
   myFunction($('#text'));
});
```

Comment: Amazing. That would great. Thanks. I will be accepting this answer in 2 min :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to name your function, so you can reference it:

```js
let text_max = 200,
    text_length,
    text_remaining,
    getTextLength = function() {
      text_length = $('#text').val().length;
      text_remaining = text_max - text_length;
      $('#count_message').html(text_length + ' / ' + text_max);
    }


/* 
 * now you can bind the function to any event:
 */

$(document).on('ready', function(){
  $('#text').on('keyup', getTextLength);
  $(window).on('load', getTextLength);
})
```

```css
#text {
  min-height: 123px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="text">As you can see, function runs once on window.load and once on each #text.keyup

Type anything...</textarea>
<span id="count_message"></span>
```

Note I do not apply the binding when the script is parsed, but on `document.ready` (when DOM parser reached `</html>`). This way I make sure `#text` is present in DOM when I bind to it. The accepted answer will fail if the script is placed before `#text` in DOM, because it executes too early.

Answer (score 0):

If by "page load" you mean when the HTML document is loaded, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

});
```

If by "page load" you mean when all the images on a page have also loaded then try this:

```
$(window).load(function() {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply call your function in in the window.onload function:

```
//call on page load
window.onload = function () {
myFunction()
}

//call on keyup
$('#text').keyup(function () {
myFunction()
});

function myFunction() {
var text_max = 200;
$('#count_message').html('0 / ' + text_max );
var text_length = $('#text').val().length;
var text_remaining = text_max - text_length;

$('#count_message').html(text_length + ' / ' + text_max);
}
```

You can keep call the same function for keyUp and for onLoad.

Comment: This will not produce the wanted result. You are still using an event listener here, which is why the text_max is not updated directly.

Comment: My mistake a didn't see the keyup listener within the function that he had created. I suspected that it had already been extracted out. I will adjust my answer.